# automatically pick random select choices in web form

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a bunch of radio fields. How can I create a script that will loop through each select group and pick a random choice from each.

I already have sections of the site implemented with scriptaculous, which has known jquery compatibility issues.

Comment: Do you know how to get the options in an array?  Do you know how to create random numbers in JS?  If so, you're 99% of the way there.  What's the specific issue you're having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how to get an array of all the selects, or how to pick one. A random number I can do.

Comment: Woops, my fault, its not selects, its radio choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work with Prototype / Scriptaculous:

```
$$('select').each(function(item){
    item.selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (item.length - 1));
});
```

Comment: in this example, what does 'select' correspond to? (class? field name?)

Comment: @MrGlass a CSS selector for HTML `<select>` elements. See http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar